# ruby deep stringify hash

Tags: json, ruby, hash, stringify

I would like to deep stringify hash in ruby like each nested hash need to be also string

input:

```rb
{"command": "subscribe", "identifier": { "channel": "TxpoolChannel" } }
```

output:

```rb
"{\"command\":\"subscribe\",\"identifier\":\"{\\\"channel\\\":\\\"TxpoolChannel\\\"}\"}"
```

is there any ready to use function or gem to achieve this result?

Comment: Your input looks like a JSON string. Maybe you shouldn't treat it as a Ruby literal in the first place?

Comment: ... and why do you escape the inner hash twice?

Comment: I am trying to connect rails cable with outside software, and action cable messages need to be  in this format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'json'

def deep_to_json(h)
  h.transform_values{|v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? deep_to_json(v) : v}.to_json
end

deep_to_json({"command": "subscribe", "identifier": { "channel": "TxpoolChannel" } })
#=> "{\"command\":\"subscribe\",\"identifier\":\"{\\\"channel\\\":\\\"TxpoolChannel\\\"}\"}"
```

But the question is, why you need to do this?

Comment: I am trying to connect rails action cable with outside software, and action cable messages need to be in this format, so I am sending normal json and want to process this json to action cable json format

Comment: The question you pose is less interesting than the rest of your answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm intrigued by the fact that a simple `to_json` won't work for the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = '{"co": "su", "id": {"ch": "Tx"}, "pig": {1: :b}, "cat": { "dog": "Woof" } }'
  #=> "{\"co\": \"su\", \"id\": {\"ch\": \"Tx\"}, \"pig\": {1: :b}, \"cat\": { \"dog\": \"Woof\" } }"
```

```
r = /
    (?=       # begin a positive lookahead
      "       # match a double-quote
      [^{}]*  # match 0* characters other than '{' and '}'
      \}      # match '}'
    )         # end positive lookahead 
    /x        # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

This regular expression is conventionally written as follows.

```
r = /(?="[^{}]*\})/
```

It matches a zero-width location preceding a double-quote that is followed by any number of characters other than a left brace, followed by a right brace, meaning that the double-quote is within a string delimited by braces. This assumes that, as in the example given in the question, braces are not nested.

[See it at rebular.com](https://rubular.com/r/ZysFhnbS7NofZu)

```
    s = str.gsub(r, "\\")
      #=> "{\"co\": \"su\", \"id\": {\\\"ch\\\": \\\"Tx\\\"}, \"pig\": {1: :b}, \"cat\": { \\\"dog\\\": \\\"Woof\\\" } }" 
    puts s
    {"co": "su", "id": {\"ch\": \"Tx\"}, "pig": {1: :b}, "cat": { \"dog\": \"Woof\" } }
```